# Selenium : Check an Element present at any point of time

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, cucumber

I'm looking for some cucumber tag like @During where it checks for an element at any point of time.For example,this code will run at all line of my test and incase the alert is present i want to do some action on that point.

```
public boolean isAlertPresent() {

    boolean presentFlag = false;

    try {

        // Check the presence of alert
        Alert alert = this.getDriver().switchTo().alert();
        // Alert present; set the flag
        presentFlag = true;
        // if present consume the alert
        alert.accept();
        //( Now, click on ok or cancel button )

    } catch (NoAlertPresentException ex) {
        // Alert not present
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    return presentFlag;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a class that implements the interface [WebDriverEventListener](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/events/WebDriverEventListener.html). This interface lets you create **before** and **after** hooks for all kinds of events such as `afterClickOn`, `afterFindBy`, `afterAlertAccept`, etc. This would let you call your method `isAlertPresent()` in one of these event hooks and deal with the popup anytime your script encounters it. 
You can alternatively have your class extend [AbstractWebDriverEventListener](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/events/AbstractWebDriverEventListener.html) abstract class if you don't need to implement all the hooks.